# ThemeMode isn't changing, Flutter via using Riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod, state-management

main.dart

```
import 'package:comman/api/data_fetching/get_user.dart';
import 'package:comman/pages/auth.dart';
import 'package:comman/pages/main_page.dart';
import 'package:comman/provider/theme_provider.dart';
import 'package:comman/provider/token_provider.dart';
import 'package:comman/provider/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import './theme/app_theme.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends ConsumerState<MyApp> {
  // accessing local storage
  final storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();
  var isTokenAvailable = true;

  // initial theme
  // var theme = ThemeMode.dark;
  // changing the theme of app


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    loadToken();
  }

  void loadToken() async {
    var token = await storage.read(key: 'token');
    if (token == null) isTokenAvailable = false;

    if (isTokenAvailable) {
      ref.read(tokenProvider.state).state = token;
      var userDetails = await getUser(token: token!);

      ref.read(userProvider).username = userDetails['username'];
      ref.read(userProvider).firstname = userDetails['first_name'];
      ref.read(userProvider).lastname = userDetails['last_name'];
      ref.read(userProvider).email = userDetails['email'];
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'COMMAN',

      // Dark Mode theme
      darkTheme: darkModeTheme,
      // Light Mode Theme
      theme: lightModeTheme,
      //initial theme
      themeMode: ref.watch(themeProvider.notifier).state,

      // body of the main page
      home: Consumer(
        builder: (context, ref, child) {
          final token = ref.watch(tokenProvider);

          if (token == null) {
            return AuthScreen(
              storage: storage,
            );
          } else {
            return HomePage(
              storage: storage,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

auth.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:comman/api/data_fetching/get_user.dart';
import 'package:comman/api/auth/register_user.dart';
import 'package:comman/api/auth/user_auth.dart';
import 'package:comman/provider/theme_provider.dart';
import 'package:comman/provider/token_provider.dart';
import 'package:comman/provider/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:comman/widgets/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class AuthScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const AuthScreen({super.key, required this.storage});

  final storage;

  @override
  ConsumerState<AuthScreen> createState() {
    return _AuthScreenState();
  }
}

class _AuthScreenState extends ConsumerState<AuthScreen> {
  // for getting values out of form and other stuff
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  // switching between login and signup content
  var isLogin = true;
  // if it is busy in uploading the credentials
  var isBusy = false;

  // user credentials and meta data
  var userName = "";
  var userEmail = "";
  var userPassword = "";
  var firstName = "";
  var lastName = "";
  File? userImage;

  // upon form submission, validating and authenticating process
  void submit() async {
    // validating if the user has entered right data, before moving on
    final isValid = formKey.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) return;

    // saving the data, in case user make changes while it's busy in backend
    formKey.currentState!.save();

    try {
      // now busy in backend
      setState(() {
        isBusy = true;
      });

      // registeration mode
      if (!isLogin) {
        print('registering user...');
        await registerUser(
          username: userName,
          password: userPassword,
          email: userEmail,
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
        );
      }

      // logging back user, or authenticating
      var token = await userAuth(
        username: userName,
        password: userPassword,
      );

      if (token.isEmpty) {
        print('nothing.............');
        return;
      }

      ref.read(tokenProvider.state).state = token;
      widget.storage.write(key: 'token', value: token);

      var userDetails = await getUser(token: token);

      ref.read(userProvider).username = userDetails['username'];
      ref.read(userProvider).firstname = userDetails['first_name'];
      ref.read(userProvider).lastname = userDetails['last_name'];
      ref.read(userProvider).email = userDetails['email'];

      print(userDetails);

      print(ref.read(userProvider.state).state.firstname);
      setState(() {
        isBusy = false;
      });

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(
              isLogin ? "Login Successfully" : "Account created Successfuly"),
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
        ),
      );
    }
    // incase things go wrong
    catch (error) {
      print(error);

      setState(() {
        isBusy = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    var logoContainer = Container(
      width: 200,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
      child: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
    );

    var authCard = Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
      // child: SingleChildScrollView(), // will use it later ***
      child: SizedBox(
        width: width > 600 ? width * 0.35 : width * 0.8,
        child: Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
          child: Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                if (!isLogin)
                  UserImagePicker(
                    onPickImage: (image) {
                      userImage = image;
                    },
                  ),

                // user name
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    label: Text("Username: "),
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null ||
                        value.trim().isEmpty ||
                        value.length < 4) {
                      return "Minimum Lenght is 4 characters!";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    userName = value!;
                  },
                ),

                // email address
                if (!isLogin)
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      label: Text("Email Address: "),
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    autocorrect: false,
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null ||
                          value.trim().isEmpty ||
                          !value.contains("@")) {
                        return "Please Enter Valid Email Address";
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      userEmail = value!;
                    },
                  ),
                // user password
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    label: Text("Password: "),
                  ),
                  obscureText: true,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null ||
                        value.trim().isEmpty ||
                        value.length < 6) {
                      return "Minimum Lenght is 6 characters!";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    userPassword = value!;
                  },
                ),

                // first name
                if (!isLogin)
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      label: Text("First Name: "),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                        return "Can't be Empty!";
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      firstName = value!;
                    },
                  ),

                // Last Name
                if (!isLogin)
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      label: Text("Last Name: "),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                        return "Can't be Empty!";
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      print("i'm here");
                      lastName = value!;
                    },
                  ),

                const SizedBox(height: 20),

                if (isBusy) const CircularProgressIndicator(),

                // signing in or signing up
                if (!isBusy)
                  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor:
                          Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                    ),
                    onPressed: submit,
                    child: Text(isLogin ? "Log in" : "Sign Up"),
                  ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                // switching between signup and login mode
                if (!isBusy)
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isLogin = !isLogin;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      isLogin
                          ? "Create New Account"
                          : "Already have an Account?",
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      // backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            // to lift the content up, when keyboard appears
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: width < 600
                  ? Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        logoContainer,
                        // form in card to take inputs for sing in / sign up
                        authCard,
                      ],
                    )
                  : Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        logoContainer,
                        authCard,
                      ],
                    ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                ref.watch(themeProvider) == ThemeMode.dark
                    ? Icons.light_mode
                    : Icons.dark_mode,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                toggleTheme(ref);
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

themeProvider.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final themeProvider = StateProvider<ThemeMode?>((ref) => ThemeMode.dark);

void toggleTheme(WidgetRef ref) {
  final currentThemeMode = ref.read(themeProvider);
  final newThemeMode =
      currentThemeMode == ThemeMode.light ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
  ref.read(themeProvider.notifier).state = newThemeMode;

  print(ref.read(themeProvider.notifier).state);
}
```

even icon is changing at auth Screen, but the theme isn't changing, also the value of update themeMode is printing accurate in terminal.

1. the issue can be in main.dart where

   themeMode: ref.watch(themeProvider.notifier).state,
2. or auth.dart, which isn't refreshing itself, but {icon is changing}

what could be the possible error?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
ref.watch(themeProvider.notifier).state,
```

with

```
ref.watch(themeProvider),
```

In general, don't "watch" the notifier.  It updates only when the notifier is entirely replaced (rare).  And accessing the notifier's state outside of notifier code is `@protected`, meaning you had to ignore a lint warning for doing this.